# Class function not called through socket

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a server.

```
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.open(2000)
loop {
  Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
    client.puts(Time.now.ctime)

    class DisplayMsg
      def self.msg(msg)
        client.puts msg
        client.close
      end
    end

    client.puts "Select 1,2,3"
    while user_input = client.gets.chomp
      case user_input
      when "1"
        client.puts "Hello"
      when "2"
        client.puts "Alo"
      when "3"
        DisplayMsg.msg("Exiting")
      end
    end
  end
}
```

It works up to the point when I try to `Exit` by calling a function defined in a class. There, the program hangs and waits.

My guess is that the function is not called, as when I swap the call to the function with `client.puts`, it works.

Any help/pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you start a child thread, the main thread will not wait for the child thread to end, and will finishe before the child thread finishes its job, unless you `join` the child thread.